# Compartir planilla con macros

Tags: excel, macros, compartir-información

Antes que nada agradezco desde ya su ayuda.

Tengo una planilla con macros que quiero compartir y me da "Error 5 " en una macro en particular.

Básicamente es una macro que ordena según el color de la celda, comparto la macro a ver si alguien me puede decir en que le estoy errando:

```
Sub Macro2Ordenar()
'
' Macro2Ordenar Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(ActiveCell _
        .Range("A1:A4071"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue _
        .Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(ActiveCell _
        .Range("A1:A4071"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue _
        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(ActiveCell _
        .Range("A1:A4071"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue _
        .Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias Israel .... queda mas claro asi. Me disculpo

Comment: Alguien puede ayudarme ?

Comment: Cuando te aparece el error dale a Depurar. Desde el editor de VBA ve pulsando F8, línea a línea, hasta llegar a la que te marque el error y comenta aquí qué fila es.
Yo he ejecutado tú código y el único error que he tenido ha sido porque no tenía puesto el autofiltro en la columna A. Pero lo he puesto y la macro se ha ejecutado sin error a pesar de no tener ninguna celda coloreada.

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita aclaraciones. ¿Qué línea te da el error? ¿Los datos van de A1:a4071 o ha cambiado el tamaño del rango?

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta. Cuando corro la macro sin compartir no tengo inconvenientes, luego de compartir el libro me da "Error 5". al intentar correr la macro.
Esto hace que no pueda compartir la informacion con otros usuarios.